# Auto create file if there is an error with the get prefix

Tags: discord.py

hello when it error I want it to automatically create folder for the server where the error happened

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open(f'Data/{message.guild.id}/settings.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    
    return prefixes['prefix']

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, case_insensitive=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `try`,`except` we can able to run a block of code if any error pops up[[....]](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)
when the guild already have the `settings.json` it returns the PREFIX! else it will create a new settings.json for that guild!.
Note that: set some values to the `data` dict! to store some values into that created settings.json

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    try:
        with open(f'Data/{message.guild.id}/settings.json', 'r') as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)
        return prefixes['prefix']
    except:
        data = {'prefix':'!'}#data is dict to save something on it
        with open(f'Data/{message.guild.id}/settings.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
        return data['prefix']
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, case_insensitive=True)
```